# How can I pass the code contained in a variable or a const to the JSX code returned by a component?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I struggle to grasp how React and JSX works together..

How can I pass the code contained in a variable or a const to the JSX code returned by a component ?

```js
import React from "react"

export default function App() {

    const element = <div>pwett or some JSX code</div>

    function Pwett() {
        return <div>pwett or some JSX code</div>
    }

    // it's the same thing !
    console.log(element)
    console.log(Pwett())

    return (
        // I know how to pass the Pwett component JSX code to the JSX code returned by App
        < Pwett />

        // How can I pass the code inside "element" to the JSX returned by App ?
        // element
        //{element}
        // dunno...
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use the `{}` to output any value inside the JSX code we are returning

```
return (
     <>
         {element}
     </>
)
```